# NSUserDefaults - how to read a saved Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I created some NSUserDefaults by creating a new Settings Bundle file and then filling out the plist it created with keys and values.
One of my values is an array called "favorites".
I'm trying to load it using:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
tempArray = [defaults arrayForKey:@"favorites"];
```

And all I'm getting back is `(null)`

One post I read said you have to manually create the NSArray and save it in your Settings Bundle for it to know that its actually a real, valid array. Is that really so? Or am I just reading the array wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code that you used to save the array?

Comment: It sounds like no array was ever saved for the key 'favorites'. If you want to do that you could do something like [defaults setObject:tempArray forKey:@"favorites"], then later you can pull that array out of user defaults like you're doing now

Comment: The new array allocation isn't necessary, also maybe there was a typo in your key, which is why I suggest you make use of constants rather than a plain string

Comment: @ErikGodard - as stated in my question: I created my NSUserDefaults using a Plist, not using code. There is no code to post for saving the array.

Comment: While saving, Make it synchronize or show me how you have saved into NSUserDefaults

Comment: Have you done anything within Settings.app to setup the array? What does the array look like in your plist?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like no NSArray was ever stored into NSUserDefaults.

To save an empty array try:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray array];
[defaults setObject:tempArray forKey:@"favorites"];
```

Now you should be able to pull the array out like you were trying to initially.

To pull data out of a plist, which is a completely separate beast from NSUserDefaults, try:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourPlistFileName" ofType:@"plist"]];
myArray = dictionary[@"favorites"];
```

Comment: Although your defaults will be saved at some point, I would recommend after the [defaults setObject..] that you then add [defaults synchronize] to write your defaults out.

Comment: As I clearly stated in my question, I did not create any arrays using code, I created my array using the Plist that came with the Settings Bundle. And _that_ is what my question is all about: does the iOS not recognize an Array that was created using a Plist? Do you HAVE to do it with code for it to "take"?

Comment: I don't remember seeing anything about a plist initially. Using a plist is different from NSUserDefaults. I've modified my answer to show how to read an array from a plist as well.